# Javascript IN operation not working with one item array

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

following the snippet bellow, why an array with **one** position is **not working properly** when using `IN` operation?

You can see that with **2 item** the operation **works fine**.

- Why this is happening?
- What's the work around?

```js
// helper function
function showResult(result) {
  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML += result+'<br/>';
}

var a = ["1"]
var b = "1"

showResult(b in a);
//false

var a = ["1","2"]
var b = "1"

showResult(b in a);
//true
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: While we're on the topic, you should read about `for..in` with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/5743988) if you haven't before. It's a common pitfall.

Comment: @4castle thanks for poiting out the question! I will read it now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) checks if an object has a key, not a value. Your second case returns `true` because any array with two elements has keys `'0'` and `'1'`. It doesn't matter that `'1'` also happens to be a value in that array; `'1' in ['foo', 'bar']` is also true.

To test if an element is in an array, you should use [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or in modern engines [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). You can use the polyfill from either of those links to get support for that method in all engines:

```
// Most engines (IE 9+)
showResult( a.indexOf( b ) >= 0 );

// Modern engines only:
showResult( a.includes( b ) );
```

Answer (score 5):

That's not what `in` is for.  `in` is *not* for searching an array for an element.  It's for searching an *object* for a *key*.

Example:

```
var x = {a: 1, b: 2};
console.log('a' in x); // true
```

Your 2nd example works because the array (object) `a` contains a key called `1`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, and what the workaround then?

Comment: @AlvaroJoao `myArray.indexOf(value) > -1` will do just what you want

Answer (score 1):

The first result is `false` because `a` does not have an index 1, while the second version of `a` has that index.

The `in` operator is not about affirming values, but properties (keys).

The confusion is maybe because CoffeeScript *does* use `in` for searching values. [See here](http://coffeescript.org/#try:a%20%3D%20%5B1%5D%0Aalert(1%20in%20a)) how it translates that into an `indexOf`